# C# WPF: Can't connect texbox.Text to label.Content via a class

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, label

Why isn't this working. I want to create a user input with a textbox in the UserInputPage and display it on the label in the UserLabelPage, but I get the error that FirstUserLabel = null. How do I fix this or am I doing it the wrong way? Thanks in advance for your time.

Dirk

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace PlayertoLabeltest
{

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static MainWindow ParentWindowRef;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Frame x:Name="ParentFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
        </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            App.ParentWindowRef = this;
            this.ParentFrame.Navigate(new UserInputPage());
        }
    }
```

**UserInputPage.xaml:**

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="singlePlayer_Input" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="150" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Button Click="UserInputToLabel_Click" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Width="100" Height="50" Content="Click Here"/>
    </Grid>
```

**UserInputPage.xaml.cs:**

```
 public partial class UserInputPage : Page
    {
        private Player FirstPlayer_Input;
        private TextBox SinglePlayer_TextBox;

        public UserInputPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UserInputToLabel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SinglePlayer_TextBox = singlePlayer_Input;
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(singlePlayer_Input.Text);
            FirstPlayer_Input = new Player(SinglePlayer_TextBox.Text);
            FirstPlayer_Input.PlayertoLabel();
            App.ParentWindowRef.ParentFrame.Navigate(new UserLabelPage());
        }
    }
```

**UserLabelPage.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label x:Name="singlePlayer_Label" Content="" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

**UserLabelPage.xaml.cs:**

```
 public partial class UserLabelPage : Page
    {
        private Player FirstPlayer_Label;

        public UserLabelPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FirstPlayer_Label = new Player(singlePlayer_Label);
        }
    }
```

**Player.cs:**

```
 class Player
    {
        private string FirstUser_Input;
        private Label FirstUser_Label;

        public Player(string text)
        {
            FirstUser_Input = text;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(FirstUser_Input);
        }

        public Player(Label FirstUser)
        {
            FirstUser_Label = FirstUser; //This one gives FirstUser_Label = null
            //FirstUser_Label.Content = "Rubeus Hagrid"; //This One works
            PlayertoLabel();
        }

        public void PlayertoLabel()
        {
            FirstUser_Label.Content = FirstUser_Input;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(FirstUser_Input);        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get the null error? Is it in the Player constructor where you try to set FirstUser_Label = FirstUser?

Comment: @AlBal, yes, luckily that is fixed now, but now FirstUser_Input cannot be implemented to FirstUser_Label.Content. The content of this label won't change after clicking on the button

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion :** I would suggest binding the values which would produce much cleaner code and easier understanding.

Nevertheless, please find below, the answer for your question

I believe, the error happens inside your UserInputPage.xaml.cs:

> `FirstPlayer_Input = new Player(SinglePlayer_TextBox.Text);`

Inside your player class, the variable `private Label FirstUser_Label;` is not initiated in one of the constructor (`public Player(string text)`).

So, Initiate it like below,

```
 `public Player(string text)
    {
        FirstUser_Input = text;
        FirstUser_Label = new Label(); //This line ensures that the FirstUser_Label is not null. It has a empty label value by default.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(FirstUser_Input);
    }`
```

*Note: Haven't tested the code myself.*

**Update: 2019-11-04**
Note: Below code is not clean. I would repeat, better approach is to use data binding and notify the property changes.

Make your label as static as below.

```
class Player
{
    private string FirstUser_Input;
    private static Label FirstUser_Label; //Making the variable as static
```

Then, when your label page initializes, modify the code as below to access the static property

```
public partial class UserLabelPage : Page
{
    private Player FirstPlayer_Label;

    public UserLabelPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        singlePlayer_Label.content = Player.FirstUser_Label.content; //singlePlayer_Lable is the x:name of the xaml object. Setting the object's content while initializing the component.
    }
}
```

*Note: I haven't tested the code. But, on theory, this should work fine.*

Comment: Thanks you very much, the error is gone. The only thing that is not working now is the implementation from TextBox.Text to Label.Content in the PlayertoLabel(). Is data binding the only option in this case?

Comment: Inside the button click " UserInputToLabel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)" , the player method converts the text content to label content. But, that label value is not applied anywhere in the label xaml page.

Comment: Creating a data binding would be a better approach. Or else, if you wish to continue with existing setup, you can make the label value inside the Player class as static. Then when your label xaml loads, you can access the static value and apply it.